# utf-8 encoding a std::string?

Tags: c++

I use a drawing api which takes in a const char* to a utf-8 encoded string. Doing myStdString.cstr() does not work, the api fails to draw the string.

for example:

```
sd::stringsomeText = "■□▢▣▤▥▦▧▨▩▪▫▬▭▮▯▰▱";
```

will render ???????????????

So how do I get the std::string to act properly?

Thanks

Comment: `std::string`, and it's member functions, should NOT EVER be used for `UTF-8`! Too many people think that UTF-8 means they can simply use their plain old `char` without considerations -- they are incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [`std::codecvt_utf8`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8) to write the string to a stringstream and then pass the result (`stringstream::str`) to the API.

Answer (score 3):

There are so many variables here it's hard to know where to begin.

First, verify that the API really and truly supports UTF-8 input, and that it doesn't need some special setup or O/S support to do so. In particular make sure it's using a font with full Unicode support.

Your compiler will be responsible for converting the source file into a string. It probably does not do UTF-8 encoding by default, and may not have an option to do so no matter what. In that case you may have to declare the string as a `std::wstring` and convert it to UTF-8 from there. Alternatively you can look up each character beyond the first 128 and encode them as hex values in the string, but that's a hassle and makes for an unreadable source.